# Can VS code auto generate jsdoc with typescript types?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

If I have some function like this:

```js
const function = (param: string) => {
 // ...
}
```

Now in VS Code if I start typing /** above so that it generates the docs, it gives this:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param param
 */
const function = (param: string) => {
 // ...
}
```

But I want it to also automatically generate the type from the typescript information, like this:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {string} param
 */
const function = (param: string) => {
 // ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what you wrote is not even valid typescript :|

Comment: related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52370, https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_jsdoc-param-completions

Answer (score 2):

There is a VS-Code extension called [Document This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oouo-diogo-perdigao.docthis) which will do the trick for you

It creates

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @param {string} param
 */
const f = (param: string) => {
  // ...
}
```

from

```
const f = (param: string) => {
  // ...
}
```

by positioning the cursor above the function and executing Ctrl+Alt+D twice

Answer (score 0):

According to this article on VS Code's site https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support there is native support for JS Docs in visual studio code.

The image shows that types needs to be inputted manually.

It looks like you need a third party plugin to do this for the time being.

If you want native support for this, create a github issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues and it could potentially be added by a contributor. Otherwise an extension might be best for this.